# I want to visit my fiancee in Germany

Tags: schengen, germany, paperwork, refugees

I am an asylum seeker in Italy and I want to visit my fiancee in Germany. I have a Nigerian passport and Identity card (carta di Identita), which lasts up to 11 years. I plan to visit her to ease our marriage procedure. Can I go by train to Germany with those documents?

Comment: Please note that if you are an asylum seeker, it is generally a very bad idea to use documents from the country you have been forced to leave (ie, Nigeria). In most cases, it would forfeit your asylum application.

Comment: @MJeffryes, that needs to be explained further. The EU uses the original documents to determine the identity of the asylum seeker, using them for this purpose is perfectly OK.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, i really appreciate you guys advice

Answer (score 9):

If you are currently *seeking* asylum, the answer is no. You must stay in Italy and complete the procedure. At the border to Germany, the police would stop you. If they determine your identity with your biometric data, they'd send you back to Italy.

Once you have been granted asylum, you should get a Schengen residence permit and also a 1951 Convention travel document. With those you can travel, see [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72885/holder-of-the-1951-convention-travel-document-issued-by-an-eu-country).

Comment: And if the application for asylum has been successful?  I suppose that Mr. White would in that case have a residence permit, which would allow travel to any other Schengen country.  Is that correct?

Comment: If he has a residence permit, he can freely travel within the Schengen area.

Comment: @phoog, edited.

Comment: @o.m. A refugee or asylee with a Schengen residence permit can travel to other Schengen countries without a visa thanks to the residence permit, regardless of the destination country's policies on visa-free travel for those with 1951 convention documents.

Comment: @phoog, wouldn't a person with that permit also have the Convention document?

Comment: @o.m. normally, yes, but note in the answer you link to: "...provided that...the holder is a legal resident of the EU/Schengen State that issued the travel document."  The best way to prove that is with the residence permit, but a Schengen residence permit satisfies the visa requirement by itself, regardless of the travel document or passport being used.