# Travelling to Ireland with an Italian 1951 Convention travel document

Tags: visas, ireland, refugees

I am a holder of the UN 1951 Convention travel document issued by Italy - an EU country. I have been traveling within the Schengen area for many years. In one week I'm going to Ireland. Do I require a visa?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Holder of the 1951 Convention travel document issued by an EU country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72885/holder-of-the-1951-convention-travel-document-issued-by-an-eu-country)

Comment: @gmauch How is this question a duplicate of that one? The linked question is asking about validity and travel to Schengen countries. It's completely different.

Comment: @MJeffryes, Well, both questions are about the same travel document, issued by an EU country and questions about validity to use it to travel within Schengen area. The [top-voted answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/74895/24596) mentions that Italy (the issuer of the travel document mentioned here) considers that document as a passport. IMHO (and also 2 close-voters already), that seems to answer OP's question, even though YMMV.

Comment: @gmauch No, it does not answer the question. That question is about document *recognition* and is limited to Schengen. The UK *recognises* the document, but also requires that 1951 document holders get a visa, whereas Ireland both recognises the document and allows visa free travel, and is **not in Schengen**. OP here is concerned with visa free travel, not merely document recognition. It's irrelevant that Italy considers it like a passport, since OP wants to travel to Ireland.

Comment: @MJeffryes [Wanna chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87756/discussion-about-question-travelling-to-ireland-with-an-italian-1951-convention-t) ?

Comment: @gmauch Not really, if by reading the questions you can't see that they are clearly very different, then I don't see how I can explain it any better to you. Once again, the question you've linked is about travel **in Schengen**. OP here wants to travel **outside Schengen**.

Comment: @MJeffryes Ireland is outside Schengen, but it's [Visa Policy is similar to the visa policy of the Schengen Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Ireland) and [every citizen of the EEA is visa exempt](http://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/moving_country/moving_to_ireland/coming_to_live_in_ireland/visa_requirements_for_entering_ireland.html#l0aabc). For me that's enough to qualify the other question as dupe, but let's leave it to community consensus.

Comment: @gmauch Someone who is a 1951 document holder from an EU state **is not an EEA citizen**. In that case they would have an EU passport. OP here wants **concrete assurance** that they can travel visa free. The fact that the visa policy of Ireland is "similar" (according to Wikipedia?) is irrelevant. The UK's visa policy is also "similar" according to Wikipedia, but OP can't travel visa free to the UK!

Answer (score 25):

## 2022 Update

Ireland [suspended its participation](https://www.irishimmigration.ie/government-agrees-to-temporarily-require-refugees-travelling-to-ireland-from-safe-european-countries-to-hold-visas/) in the European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees on 19 July 2022, for a period of 12 months. This means that 1951 convention travel document holders need a visa to travel to Ireland. Beyond this date, it is possible that Ireland will announce a further suspension at some point. Convention document holders should assume they will need a visa to travel to Ireland beyond this date.

### Original answer follows

The Irish government [provides a tool](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/check-irish-visa) for determining what visa you require to travel to Ireland. Putting in your details shows that you do not need a visa to travel to Ireland for any stay up to 90 days.

Ireland is a party to the European Agreement on the Abolition of Visas for Refugees. Since you have a 1951 Convention document issued by another party to the agreement, [you can travel without a visa](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Convention+travel+documents). However, note that the UK is not (anymore) a party to the agreement. You would need a visa if you were to travel to Ireland via the UK, and you would need a visa if you were to cross the border into Northern Ireland, despite the lack of border controls.

Comment: For anyone, like me, who wondered whether "_the UK is not (anymore) a party to the agreement_" was connected to Brexit, the UK pulled out of the agreement in 2003 ([Declaration of suspension](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list/-/conventions/treaty/031/declarations?p_auth=X4MPrhs0&_coeconventions_WAR_coeconventionsportlet_enVigueur=false&_coeconventions_WAR_coeconventionsportlet_searchBy=state&_coeconventions_WAR_coeconventionsportlet_codePays=UK&_coeconventions_WAR_coeconventionsportlet_codeNature=10)).

Comment: Funny that an Italian permanent resident would need an Irish visa (unless eligible otherwise through their citizenship), but a refugee doesn't...

Comment: @JonathanReez Being a refugee doesn’t have many perks, so it’s nice that they’re afforded this one!